# non-existant parameter "mcx" when using app/console

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am currently trying to go through the api-platform tutorial on https://api-platform.com/doc/1.0/getting-started/api but at the point where I use the console script (database creation), I just get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]  
You have requested a non-existent parameter "mcx".
```

They mention to use the [api-platform] tag here, but it apparently does not yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who runs into this kind of issue, check your parameters.yml file.  I apparently chose too complex of a "secret" as it doesn't like percent (%) symbols in values and tries to parse them as separate parameters to be injected.